# Get the width of an existing td element

Tags: jquery, width, html-table

I have a table that is created dynamically with jQuery and it has a number of columns. I don't know what is going to be in the table, or how many columns there will be. Depending on what is inside of the td, each td will have a different width. What I want to do is to get the width of the td and use it for later.

This is what my table can look like. https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV3v6.jpg

As you can see it has different sized columns. So I just want to go and get the width of each element. This is my code:

```
var topTds = $("#ResultSetTable tr:first");
topTds = topTds.children();
console.log(topTds);
//for each of the tds we want to go and get their scrollwidth
for(var m = 0; m < topTds.length; m++){
    console.log(topTds[m], "client: ", topTds[m].clientWidth, "offset ", topTds[m].offsetWidth, "scroll ", topTds[m].scrollWidth);
}
```

As you can see I've tried all the different width things I can think of, but they aren't printing out the right number. This is the result that I am getting https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrkkR.jpg

However when I scroll over using chrome I get different numbers, and it the chrome numbers are the correct ones. This is what chrome shows https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Yx3m.jpg

So basically I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using jQuery, you can take advantage of the `width()` method provided.

```
for(var m = 0; m < topTds.length; m++) {
    console.log(topTds[m], "jQuery width: ", topTds.eq(m).width());
}
```

`clientWidth`, `offsetWidth` and `scrollWidth` represent different quantities, and computing the final width of a HTML element can be quite tricky because of CSS properties and box model.
Besides, you should check when `console.log` is called, if all the CSS and JavaScript was loaded, and the table filled with data: these can be the reasons for the strange values you get.

In my experience, jQuery's `width()` never failed in computing the actual width of an object.

Some reference:

- [scrollWidth at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollWidth)
- [clientWidth at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.clientWidth)
- [offsetWidth at
  MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetWidth)
- [Reference for `width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/)